# Github: Any ideas on how to have merging dependencies between commits/repos?

Tags: github, github-api, githooks

Consider two repos, `webui_repo` and `webservice_repo`, that are two interdependent systems (the web UI and service, respectively).

As you can imagine, the `webui` depends on `webservice`, but imagine that they've grown a lot and are managed by two teams, thus a considerable amount of effort is required to get things going, and that's ok.

But sometimes one of them gets deployed and either breaks retro-compatibility or expects a feature that hasn't been deployed yet. In order to alleviate that, I thought of a dependency-check feature, based on commit keywords (similar to [closing issues using keywords](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-using-keywords/)):

```
This is my commit message. Depends on: webservice_repo/commit/<commit_hash>
```

I've done a small research and couldn't find any existing feature that provides this. I've also tried to find out if Github provides any extension/customization to the merge process, but no answer there as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: Git versions sources, not releases or deployments. You should version your releases independently of git, and add logic to your deployment process to validate aconfiguration before deploying.

Comment: Git is indeed responsible for source code versioning, on another hand Github is a tool that offers much more features. And this is what I'm looking at, the feature of merging a PR, for instance. I would like to either prevent or at least warn the user about unfulfilled dependencies before she does a merge.

Comment: Git offers triggers for other software to do stuff. Like deployment. It's whatever other software you use for deployment that you need to investigate.

Comment: I have found this article, https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statuses/, that documents the Statuses endpoint of the GitHub API. I will create a small service that can check for the said dependencies. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I still think this should be a GitHub's feature, I have written a small web app to provide this functionality: [Pierre DeCheck](https://github.com/alvarocavalcanti/pierre-decheck)

I hope it's useful to more people. Also, it's open source, start contributing already! :)